# How to Save TPath Data As a `.jpg` Image

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm new to Delphi. I need a help for complete my code. I just drawing a path. Now i want to save it to Android local storage as an Image format.
This is my code

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
if ssLeft in Shift then
    Path1.Data.MoveTo(PointF(X,Y) - Path1.BoundsRect.TopLeft);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
 if ssLeft in Shift then
    Path1.Data.LineTo(PointF(X,Y) - Path1.BoundsRect.TopLeft);
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //save code goes here
end;
```

Comment: What is `Path1` and what is `Path1.Data`? I know [`TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.IOUtils.TPath) as a class for directory operations.

Comment: Actually I used `TPath` component for that. `Path1: TPath;`

Comment: @DarshanaPathum It's a different `TPath`. It's [`FMX.Objects.TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Objects.TPath). Were you to have provided a [mcve] there could have been no doubt.

Comment: Never used FMX, but David's link shows that TPath has a PaintTo method with which you can draw the TPath to a canvas. This can be a canvas of a TBitmap, which according to [this documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.SaveToFile) can be saved to a Jpeg directly (in contrast to the VCL TBitmap).

Answer (score 1):

The only way that worked for me:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Path1.MakeScreenshot.SaveToFile('image.jpg'); // Save code
end;
```

None of the following options work:

```
Path1.Canvas.Bitmap.SaveToFile('image.jpg'); // Results in AV
Path1.Canvas.Bitmap.Canvas.Bitmap.SaveToFile('image.jpg'); // Also results in AV
```